# How to add a border-bottom or a horizontal line below the table heading

Tags: html, css

I want to create a **Horizontal line** below **th**. Below is what I want to achieve

[image: Table underline required]

I have created the table and all using the following html markup

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <th>Table</th>
        <th>&#37; of Time Index Used</th>
        <th>Rows in Table</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>tweet_groups</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>20,488</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

So how do I add the horizontal line??

Comment: Have you tried like anything? Why didn't it work for you?

Comment: `border-bottom: 1px solid #000`

Comment: I used border-bottom on th but it gave small spaces between the horziontal lines..

Comment: use border bottom on tr not on th

Comment: create fiddle or Show you CSS also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tr:first-child{ border-bottom: 1px solid #555;}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
th
{
 border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
table tr:first-child{border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
```